# skipping empty list and continuing with function

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, try-catch, empty-list

**Background**

```
import pandas as pd
Names =    [list(['Jon', 'Smith', 'jon', 'John']),
               list([]),
               list(['Bob', 'bobby', 'Bobs'])]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text' : ['Jon J Smith is Here and jon John from ', 
                                       '', 
                                       'I like Bob and bobby and also Bobs diner '], 

                          'P_ID': [1,2,3], 
                          'P_Name' : Names

                         })

#rearrange columns
df = df[['Text', 'P_ID', 'P_Name']]
df

    Text                                      P_ID  P_Name
0   Jon J Smith is Here and jon John from       1   [Jon, Smith, jon, John]
1                                               2   []
2   I like Bob and bobby and also Bobs diner    3   [Bob, bobby, Bobs]
```

**Goal**

I would like to use the following function

```
df['new']=df.Text.replace(df.P_Name,'**BLOCK**',regex=True)
```

but skip row 2, since it has an empty list `[]`

**Tried**

I have tried the following

```
try:
    df['new']=df.Text.replace(df.P_Name,'**BLOCK**',regex=True) 
except ValueError:
    pass
```

But I get the following output

```
                        Text                P_ID    P_Name
0   Jon J Smith is Here and jon John from       1   [Jon, Smith, jon, John]
1                                               2   []
2   I like Bob and bobby and also Bobs diner    3   [Bob, bobby, Bobs]
```

**Desired Output**

```
   Text P_ID P_Name  new
0                     `**BLOCK**` J `**BLOCK**` is Here and `**BLOCK**` `**BLOCK**` from
1                      []  
2                      I like `**BLOCK**` and `**BLOCK**` and also `**BLOCK**` diner
```

**Question**

How do I get my desired output by skipping row 2 and continuing with my function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locate the rows which do not have an empty list and use your `replace` method only on those rows:

```
# Boolean indexing the rows which do not have an empty list
m = df['P_Name'].str.len().ne(0)

df.loc[m, 'New'] = df.loc[m, 'Text'].replace(df.loc[m].P_Name,'**BLOCK**',regex=True)
```

**Output**

```
                                        Text  P_ID                   P_Name                                                  New
0     Jon J Smith is Here and jon John from      1  [Jon, Smith, jon, John]  **BLOCK** J **BLOCK** is Here and **BLOCK** **BLOCK** from 
1                                       Test     2                       []                                                  NaN
2  I like Bob and bobby and also Bobs diner      3       [Bob, bobby, Bobs]  I like **BLOCK** and **BLOCK** and also **BLOCK**s diner
```

Comment: I have a slight modification to the code above. I posted a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57242540/modification-of-skipping-empty-list-and-continuing-with-function. Would be great to get your input if possible