# modification of skipping empty list and continuing with function

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, text, empty-list

**Background**

The following code is slightly modified from [skipping empty list and continuing with function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57236878/skipping-empty-list-and-continuing-with-function)

```
import pandas as pd
Names =    [list(['Jon', 'Smith', 'jon', 'John']),
               list([]),
               list(['Bob', 'bobby', 'Bobs']),
               list([]),
               list([])]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text' : ['Jon J Smith is Here and jon John from ', 
                                       'get nothing from here', 
                                       'I like Bob and bobby and also Bobs diner ',
                                        'nothing here too',
                                        'same here'
                            ], 

                          'P_ID': [1,2,3, 4,5], 
                          'P_Name' : Names

                         })

    #rearrange columns
df = df[['Text', 'P_ID', 'P_Name']]
df

                                 Text         P_ID  P_Name
0   Jon J Smith is Here and jon John from       1   [Jon, Smith, jon, John]
1   get nothing from here                       2   []
2   I like Bob and bobby and also Bobs diner    3   [Bob, bobby, Bobs]
3   nothing here too                            4   []
4   same here                                   5   []
```

**Working code**

The following bit of code works taken from [skipping empty list and continuing with function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57236878/skipping-empty-list-and-continuing-with-function)

```
m = df['P_Name'].str.len().ne(0)
df.loc[m, 'New'] = df.loc[m, 'Text'].replace(df.loc[m].P_Name,'**BLOCK**',regex=True)
```

And produces the following `New` column in `df`

```
            Text   P_ID  P_Name   New
0                                 **BLOCK** J **BLOCK** is Here and **BLOCK** **BLOCK** ...
1                                 NaN
2                                 I like **BLOCK** and **BLOCK** and also **BLOCK** d..
3                                 NaN 
4                                 NaN
```

**Desired Output**

However, instead of `NaN` in row `1`, `3`, `4`, I would like to keep the original text e.g. `get nothing from here` as seen below

```
            Text   P_ID  P_Name   New
0                                 **BLOCK** J **BLOCK** is Here and **BLOCK** **BLOCK** ...
1                                 get nothing from here
2                                 I like **BLOCK** and **BLOCK** and also **BLOCK** d..
3                                 nothing here too 
4                                 same here
```

**Question**

How do I tweak the code below to achieve my desired output?

```
m = df['P_Name'].str.len().ne(0)
df.loc[m, 'New'] = df.loc[m, 'Text'].replace(df.loc[m].P_Name,'**BLOCK**',regex=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@tawab_shakeel is close. Just add:

```
df['New'].fillna(df['Text'], inplace=True)
```

`fillna` will catch the correct value from `df['Text']`.

---

I can also propose an alternative solution using the [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module for regex.

```
def replacing(x):
    if len(x['P_Name']) > 0:
        return re.sub('|'.join(x['P_Name']), '**BLOCK**', x['Text'])
    else:
        return x['Text']

df['New'] = df.apply(replacing, axis=1)
```

The `apply` method applies the `replacing` function to each row, and substitution is done by the [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) function.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this line in the end [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html)

```
df['New'].fillna(df['Text'],inplace=True)
```

Comment: I updated my code to reflect what I am looking for. This code would work in for one row in this example but I have a real `df` that is a few thousand rows long. So I updated my example here to reflect this fact

Comment: @ER_18 you want to will every nan with difference values ?