# alter specific characters in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, text, replace

**Background**

I have the following `df` which contains tokenized `Text` and `P_Name` columns and is a modification of [including word boundary in string modification to be more specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262864/including-word-boundary-in-string-modification-to-be-more-specific)

```
P_Name = [list(['Steven', 'I','Jobs']),
          list(['A', 'Ma', 'Mary']),
          list(['U','Kar', 'Jacob'])]

Text =  [list(['Steven', 'I','Jobs', 'likes', 'apples','I', 'too']),
        list(['A','i', 'like', 'A', 'lot', 'of','sports','cares', 'A', 'Ma', 'Mary']),
        list(['the','U', 'Kar', 'Jacob', 'what', 'about', 'U', 'huh','?'])]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text' : Text,  
                  'P_ID': [1,2,3], 
                  'P_Name' : P_Name,

                 })
df
   P_ID    P_Name            Text
0   1   [Steven, I, Jobs]   [Steven, I, Jobs, likes, apples, I, too]
1   2   [A, Ma, Mary]       [A, i, like, A, lot, of, sports, cares, A, Ma, Mary]
2   3   [U, Kar, Jacob]     [the, U, Kar, Jacob, what, about, U, huh, ?]
```

**Goal**

1) use the name in `P_Name` to block the corresponding text in the `Text` column by placing `**block**`

2) produce a new column `New_Text`

**Tried**

From [including word boundary in string modification to be more specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262864/including-word-boundary-in-string-modification-to-be-more-specific)

I have modified the code and tried the following

```
df['New_Text']=[pd.Series(x).replace(dict.fromkeys(y,'**block**') ).str.cat(sep=' ')for x , y in zip(df['Text'],df['P_Name'])]
```

Which gives close to what I want but not quite since some letters are being inappropriately labeled `**block**`  e.g `I` in row `0`

```
 P_ID P_Name Text New_Text
    0             [**block**, **block**, **block**, likes, apples, **block**, too]
    1             [**block**, i, like, **block**, lot, of, sports, cares, **block**, **block**, **block**]
    2             [the, **block**, **block**, **block**, what, about, **block**, huh, ?]
```

**Desired Output**

```
P_ID P_Name Text New_Text
    0              [**block**, **block**, **block**, likes, apples, I, too]
    1              [A, i, like, A, lot, of, sports, cares, **block**, **block**, **block**]
    2              [the, **block**, **block**, **block**, what, about, U, huh, ?]
```

**Question**

How do I further modify

```
df['New_Text']=[pd.Series(x).replace(dict.fromkeys(y,'**block**') ).str.cat(sep=' ')for x , y in zip(df['Text'],df['P_Name'])]
```

or use new code to achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want each ordered occurrence of the `P_Name` sequence in the `Text` tokens. This can be achieved by iterating over the `Text` tokens & checking for equality on the entire `P_Name` tokens:

```py
df["New_Text"] = df["Text"].apply(lambda tokens: tokens.copy())  # copy original tokens
for tokens, name in zip(df["New_Text"], df["P_Name"]):
    for i, token in enumerate(tokens):
        if tokens[i:i + len(name)] == name:
            tokens[i:i + len(name)] = ["**block**"] * len(tokens[i:i + len(name)])
```

Depending on your use case you might have the untokenised `Text` (& `P_name`) available. If so, then substring matching can be done instead, & then perform tokenisation after.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried running the code above and I get an error `NameError: name 'masked_tokens' is not defined`